# eaccelerator PHP error

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a Wordpress plugin and I'm getting the following error. The weird thing is I checked the plugins' source and I really don't understand why it would need those scripts.

> [30-May-2011 11:10:03] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   [30-May-2011 11:10:03] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ffmpeg.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: When and where you get this error? after installing?  at the time of installing??

Comment: I can install the plugin without any problems. After that my error log gets full of this errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is very clear . file not found.

is the file is there in the server.

i think you have to enable these plugins in php.ini and restart the server

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/